# Password encryption on Snowsql config file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Any one has ideas who implemented securing password  on snow sql config file apart from restricting access to file?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to storing a password, for interactive use of Snowsql consider browser based SSO authentication [Using a Web Browser for Federated Authentication/SSO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql-start.html#using-a-web-browser-for-federated-authentication-sso)

For scenarios where that is not feasible, consider storing the password in an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put the password in your config file then it is going to be in plain text and you can only restrict it by restricting access to the file.